# Neo4j Create new label based on other labels with certain properties

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I need to create Trajectories based on Points.

- A Trajectory can contain any number of Points that meet certain criteria.
  Criteria are: cameraSid, trajectoryId, classType and classQual should be equal.
  The difference in time (at) of each point must be less or equal to 1 hour.
- In order to create a Trajectory we need at least one point.
- In order to associate a new point to an existing Trajectory, the latest associated Point of the trajectory must be no older and 1 hour compared to the new point.
  If the new Point has the exact same properties but is older than 1 hour, then a new Trajectory need to be created.

I've been reading a lot but, I cannot make this work as it should.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
MATCH (p:Point)
WHERE NOT (:Trajectory)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
WITH p.cameraSid AS cameraSid, p.trajectoryId AS trajectoryId, p.classType AS classType, p.classQual AS classQual, COLLECT(p) AS points
UNWIND points AS point
MERGE (trajectory:Trajectory{trajectoryId:point.trajectoryId, cameraSid: point.cameraSid, classType: point.classType, classQual: point.classQual, date: date(datetime(point.at))})
MERGE (trajectory)-[:CONTAINS{at:point.at}]->(point)
```

I have no idea how to create this sort of condition (1hr or less) in the MERGE clause.

Here are the neo4j queries to create some data

```
// Create points
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://uca54485eb4c5d2a6869053af475.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/AmR2pn0hC0c-CQW_mSS-TDqHQyi7MNVjPvqffQHhSIyMP37D7UMtfODdHDkNWi6-HqzQdp4ob2Q3326g6imEd26F3sdNJyJuAeNa8wJA2o_E6A/file?dl=1#' AS line
CREATE (:Point{trajectoryId: line[0],at: line[1],cameraSid: line[2],activity: line[3],x: line[4],atEpochMilli: line[5],y: line[6],control: line[7],classQual: line[8],classType: line[9],uniqueIdentifier: line[10]})

// Create Trajectory based on Points
MATCH (p:Point)
WHERE NOT (:Trajectory)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
WITH p.cameraSid AS cameraSid, p.trajectoryId AS trajectoryId, p.classType AS classType, p.classQual AS classQual, COLLECT(p) AS points
UNWIND points AS point
MERGE (trajectory:Trajectory{trajectoryId:point.trajectoryId, cameraSid: point.cameraSid, classType: point.classType, classQual: point.classQual, date: date(datetime(point.at))})
MERGE (trajectory)-[:CONTAINS{at:point.at}]->(point)
```

If the link to the CSV file does not work, here is an [alternative](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zzkxfqqzj6td4n/export.csv?dl=0), in this case, you will have to download the file and then import it locally from your neo4j instance.

Comment: The Dropbox link in your `LOAD CSV` is a 404 so there's no data to recreate your issue - can you edit in an amended link please?

Comment: @Pablissimo I have updated the link, would you please try again?

Comment: Getting a 403 now as though it's not a public link maybe?

Comment: @Pablissimo Looks like those links expire quite quickly, do you mind downloading and importing the file locally? Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zzkxfqqzj6td4n/export.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is one of those *just because you **can** do it in one Cypher statement doesn't mean you should* situations, and you will almost certainly find this easier to do in application code.

Regardless, it *can* be done using APOC and by introducing an `instanceId` unique property on your Trajectory nodes.

### Possible solution

This almost certainly won't scale, and you'll want indexes (discussed later based on educated guesswork).

First we need to change your import script to make sure that the `at` property is a `datetime` and not just a string (otherwise we end up peppering the queries with `datetime()` calls:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///export.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Point{trajectoryId: line[0], at: datetime(line[1]), cameraSid: line[2], activity: line[3],x: line[4], atEpochMilli: line[5], y: line[6], control: line[7], classQual: line[8], classType: line[9], uniqueIdentifier: line[10]})
```

The following then appears to take your sample data set and add Trajectories per your requirements (and can be run whenever new Points are added).

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate( 
'
MATCH (p: Point) 
WHERE NOT (:Trajectory)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
RETURN p
ORDER BY p.at
',
'
OPTIONAL MATCH (t: Trajectory { trajectoryId: p.trajectoryId, cameraSid: p.cameraSid, classQual: p.classQual, classType: p.classType })-[:CONTAINS]-(trajPoint:Point)
WITH p, t, max(trajPoint.at) as maxAt, min(trajPoint.at) as minAt
WITH p, max(case when t is not null AND (
      (p.at <= datetime(maxAt) + duration({ hours: 1 })) 
      AND 
      (p.at >= datetime(minAt) - duration({ hours: 1 }))
  ) 
  THEN t.instanceId ELSE NULL END) as instanceId
MERGE (tActual: Trajectory { trajectoryId: p.trajectoryId, cameraSid: p.cameraSid, classQual: p.classQual, classType: p.classType, instanceId: COALESCE(instanceId, randomUUID()) })
ON CREATE SET tActual.date = date(datetime(p.at))
MERGE (tActual)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
RETURN instanceId
',
{ parallel: false, batchSize: 1 })
```

### Explanation

The problem as posed is tricky because the decision on whether or not to create a new Trajectory or add the point to an existing one depends entirely on how we handled all prior Points. That means two things:

- We need to process the Points in order to make sure we create reliable Trajectories - we start with the earliest, and work up
- We need each creation or amend of a Trajectory to be immediately visible for the processing of the next Point - that is to say that we need to handle each Point in isolation, as though it were a mini-transaction

We'll use `apoc.periodic.iterate` with a `batchSize` of 1 to give us the behaviour we need.

The first parameter builds the set of nodes to be processed - all those Points which aren't currently part of a Trajectory, sorted by their timestamp.

The second parameter to `apoc.periodic.iterate` is where the magic's happening so let's break that down - given a point `p` that isn't part of a Trajectory so far:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (t: Trajectory { trajectoryId: p.trajectoryId, cameraSid: p.cameraSid, classQual: p.classQual, classType: p.classType })-[:CONTAINS]-(trajPoint:Point)
WITH p, t, max(trajPoint.at) as maxAt, min(trajPoint.at) as minAt
WITH p, max(case when t is not null AND (
      (p.at <= datetime(maxAt) + duration({ hours: 1 })) 
      AND 
      (p.at >= datetime(minAt) - duration({ hours: 1 }))
  ) 
  THEN t.instanceId ELSE NULL END) as instanceId
```

- Finds any Trajectory that matches the key fields and that contain a Point that's within an hour of the incoming point `p` and pick out its `instanceId` property if we find a suitable match (or the biggest one we found if there are multiple matches - we just want to ensure there's zero or one rows by this point)
- We'll see what `instanceId` is all about in a minute, but consider it a unique identifier for a given `Trajectory`

```
MERGE (tActual: Trajectory { trajectoryId: p.trajectoryId, cameraSid: p.cameraSid, classQual: p.classQual, classType: p.classType, instanceId: COALESCE(instanceId, randomUUID()) })
ON CREATE SET tActual.date = date(datetime(p.at))
```

- Ensure that there's a Trajectory that matches the incoming point's key fields - if the previous code found a matching Trajectory then the `MERGE` has no work to do. Otherwise create the new Trajectory - we'll add a property `instanceId` to a new random UUID if we didn't match a Trajectory earlier to compel the `MERGE` to create a new node (since no other will exist with that UUID, even if one matches all the other key fields)

```
MERGE (tActual)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
RETURN instanceId
```

- `tActual` is now the Trajectory that the incoming point `p` should belong to - create the `:CONTAINS` relationship

The third parameter is vital:

```
{ parallel: false, batchSize: 1 })
```

- **Important**: For this to work, each iteration of the 'inner' Cypher statement has to happen exactly in order, so we force a `batchSize` of 1 and disable parallelism to prevent `APOC` from scheduling the batches in any way other than one-at-a-time.

### Indexing

I think the performance of the above is going to degrade quickly as the size of the import grows and the number of Trajectories increases. At a minimum I *think* you'll want a composite index on

- `:Trajectory(trajectoryId, cameraSid, classQual, classType)` - so that the initial match to find candidate trajectories for a given Point is quick
- `:Trajectory(trajectoryId, cameraSid, classQual, classType, instanceId)` - so that the `MERGE` at the end finds the existing Trajectory to add to quickly, if one exists

However - that's guesswork from eyeballing the query, and unfortunately you can't see into the query properly to tell what the execution plan is because we're using `apoc.periodic.iterate` - an `EXPLAIN` or `PROFILE` will just tell you that there's one procedure call costing 1 db hit, which is true but not helpful.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I will try it out asap. Quick question, in these nodes, what indexes do you think will need to be there no matter what?

Comment: I have tried this and unless I did something wrong, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Take a look at this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilzad01jm3n3kzn/export.csv?dl=0 it contains only 5 Points, from those points, 3 Trajectories should be created, but instead, only one Trajectory is being created.

Comment: Ah, there's a typo in the query but it looks like a data type issue as well that I'd resolved my end and forgot about. Will update the answer.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense, it's now working with your changes. Thanks for adding the extra info about the indexes!